# Clone a table, remove rows, restore table

Tags: jquery, html-table, clone, replacewith

I need some help on this one.
I have a table with a select-filter, and every time the filter changes I need to reset the table to its original state and set the filter --> delete unused rows (because rows cannot be hidden right?).

So here's what I tried, but did not work. tableParts is the div containing my table. I figured out the change-event is only fired once, so no more alerts after the first one. What am I doing wrong? it's still work in progress, so the switch is not fully programmed because I already struggled on the change event...

```js
var originalContent;

$(document).ready(function() {
    originalContent =  $('#tableParts').clone();

    $('#selectState').addEventListener('change', changeFilter());

});

function changeFilter() {
    $('#tableParts').replaceWith(originalContent);

    switch (this.value) {
        case "0":
            alert("0");
            break;
        case "1":
            alert("1");
            break;
        case "2":
            alert("2");
            break;
        case "3":
            alert("3");
            break;
        case "4":
            $(".label-danger").closest('tr').remove();
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="tableParts" class="project-list">
  <table id="table_participants" class="table footable table-hover" data-page-size="1000" data-filter=#filter>
  
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"></th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>
          <select id="selectState" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr class="footable-even">
        <td><span class="footable-toggle"></span>
          <input type="hidden" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="1">                      </td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td class="client-status"><span class="label-danger"></span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="footable-odd">
        <td><span class="footable-toggle"></span>
          <input type="hidden" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="1">                      </td>
        <td>454</td>
        <td class="client-status"><span class="label-new"></span></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    
  </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows *can* be hidden, which is the easiest to implement a filter (without another library).

There are a few mistakes in your code:

- `addEventListener()` works on native DOM elements, not on jQuery collections. Use `on()` instead.
- Don't *call* the function you pass as event handler, but just pass it (no parentheses).

Here is a snippet that uses `toggle()` to hide/show the rows that match the filter:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectState').on('change', changeFilter);
});

function changeFilter() {
    var filterValue = this.value;
    $('#tableParts tr').slice(1).each(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(".client-status", this).text() === filterValue ||
                       filterValue === '');
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableParts" class="project-list">
  <table id="table_participants" class="table footable table-hover" data-page-size="1000" data-filter=#filter>
  
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"></th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>
          <select id="selectState" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option value="">(all)</option>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr class="footable-even">
        <td><span class="footable-toggle"></span>
          <input type="hidden" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="1">                      </td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td class="client-status"><span class="label-danger">1</span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="footable-odd">
        <td><span class="footable-toggle"></span>
          <input type="hidden" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="1">                      </td>
        <td>454</td>
        <td class="client-status"><span class="label-new">2</span></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: thank you, that's a very slick solution, didn't know about toggling rows. somehow i cannot get the filter to work, even though filterValue and $(".client-status", this).text() do match (2 e.g.)

Comment: i refactored it to this: if($(".client-status", this).text() === filterValue){alert("match");$(".client-status", this).toggle();} the alert gets fired correctly, but nothing else happens

Comment: It works in the snippet, so there must be something different in your setup. Note that your refactored attempt would not work well anyway, since it only does something when the value is a match, and that something is toggling the visibility without any knowledge whether it was visible or not, and secondly it does nothing when the value is different. Can you provide a fiddle that illustrates the issue?

Comment: Great to hear. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var originalContent;

$(document).ready(function() {
    originalContent =  $('#tableParts').clone();

    $('#selectState').change(function(){
      changeFilter(this);
    });

});

function changeFilter(obj) {
    //$('#tableParts').replaceWith(originalContent);
    switch ($(obj).val()) {
        case "0":
            alert("0");
            break;
        case "1":
            alert("1");
            break;
        case "2":
            alert("2");
            break;
        case "3":
            alert("3");
            break;
        case "4":
            $(".label-danger").closest('tr').remove();
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableParts" class="project-list">
  <table id="table_participants" class="table footable table-hover" data-page-size="1000" data-filter=#filter>
  
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"></th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>
          <select id="selectState" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr class="footable-even">
        <td><span class="footable-toggle"></span>
          <input type="hidden" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="1">                      </td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td class="client-status"><span class="label-danger"></span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="footable-odd">
        <td><span class="footable-toggle"></span>
          <input type="hidden" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="list[members][0][linked]" value="1">                      </td>
        <td>454</td>
        <td class="client-status"><span class="label-new"></span></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks, but reseting the table is missing. and i included jquery, sorry for not posting that.